# Replacing getDerivedStateFromProps with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm converting a class component to a function component and wanted to see if `useEffect()` could replace the following static function

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    const { path } = props.match;
    if (path === '/login') {
      return { loginStatus: true };
    } else {
      return { loginStatus: false };
    }
  }
```

Following is the new replacement function.  It's doing what it's supposed to be doing, which is to change the state according to the props, but I'm not too familiar with useEffect() and I'm just wondering if I'm not losing anything by converting to this.

```
const { path } = props.match
useEffect(() => {
    if (path ==='/login'){
        setLoginStatus(true)
    } else {
    setLoginStatus(false)
    }
}, [ path ])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops)

You can have a state for the previous `path` and the current `path` and only call `setLoginStatus` when they are different.

If you only want to `setLoginStatus(true)` when `path == 'login'` then using the `useEffect` is correct.

This part of the code will only run when `path` changes. And this happens because of `[ path ]`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (path ==='/login'){
        setLoginStatus(true)
    } else {
    setLoginStatus(false)
    }
}, [ path ])
```

And if you are using some router, probably your effect will run only in the initial render.

> I'm just wondering if I'm not losing anything by converting to this.

No, it's fine, that's the way you should do it

Also take a look at [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

And [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)