# Noticeable delay with useEffect instead of getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state

I'm trying to rewrite a class component as a functional component. The original component uses `getDerivedStateFromProps` and I'm using [this solution to replace it with useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173913/replacing-getderivedstatefromprops-with-useeffect). It works but the problem is that there is a small but noticable delay with the `useEffect` approach that wasn't there before.

**The component:**

It is a dropdown component that receives its value as a prop. The user can change its value by selecting another option, which will trigger an ajax call eventually changing the prop value. Since this takes some time, I also added the value as state so that the change is automatic in response to user input. Also there may be other external events that change the props value, and in this case I want to rerender with the new props.

**Why need getDerivedStateFromProps / useEffect?**

This gets me in a situation where the input is both relying on props and state at the same time, as in a mix of controlled and uncontrolled. I want to keep a state so that change is automatic in response to user input, but also I want to replace that state when the prop value changes.

I ran through many articles such as [You probably don't need derived state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) but I still believe I need it. If you think I still don't need it, please let me know.

**The solution:**

So this works:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return (props.value != state.value) ? {value: props.value} : {};
}
```

And now I changed it to a functional component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);

useEffect(() => {
  if (props.value != value) setValue(props.value);
}, [props.value]);
```

And this works too!

**The new problem:**

However, when there is an external props change, with `getDerivedStateFromProps` it looks automatic but with `useEffect` there is a small but noticeable delay. I think this is because it's going from:

`getDerivedStateFromProps` changes state -> render

to:

render -> `useEffect` changes state -> another render

Any ideas how to make `useEffect` as performant as `getDerivedStateFromProps`? Or any other way to improve this?